# Audio is overdriven and delayed in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Normally my audio works fine but like every 15 minutes my audio gets overdriven, delayed and crackled and I don't know why.

I read on Reddit the command `killall pulseaudio` should help and it did, but in the next minutes it starts again. But the strange thing is when I'm in a game like CS:GO or Minecraft the Audio works fine even after hours.

What can I try to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I'm running 20.04 as well having the same issue. I've figured out that when this happens to me it's accompanied by my audio setting automatically switching from 5.1 surround output to analog stereo for some reason. Upon switching it back, it works fine, but after switching I usually have issues with buffering, currently my audio is delayed maybe 300ms

Hoping to find a solution soon. I do not have any audio related packages installed apart from recent installation and latest updates

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I hope i'll find a solution aswell, i can let you know if you want.

Comment: Any updates to this issue? I'm still having the same thing happen

Comment: Well a few days ago, i think i fixed it. I installed "pavucontrol" to see everything. And I noticed when this issue happens there are some other soundsources named "dispatcher". And I use my screen with HDMI so i switched the output from the dispatchers to HDMI (to the speaker from my monitor) and it never happened again.